# Use one Fragment in a ViewPager multiple times

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager, fragment

Is it possible to use one fragment in a viewpager multiple times? I am trying to build a dynamically updated UI using ViewPager.
I want to use the same design, basically the same fragment with different data for every page, like a listview adapter.

Comment: AFAIK, this will not work. You could use a `GestureDetector` to watch for swipes on your existing fragment.

Comment: BTW, to clarify, I am assuming that you mean that you want to use a single fragment *instance* -- if you mean that you want to just use a single fragment *class*, that is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can instantiate the same Fragment class for every page in your ViewPager, passing the position of the ViewPager to control what to display. Something like that:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mIndex;

    public MyFragment(int index) {
        mIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        switch(mIndex){
            case 0:
            // do you things..
            case 1:
            // etcetera
        }             
    }
}
```

then, in you FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new MyFragment(position);
    }
}
```

That way you can reuse most of your code changing only what you need in the switch/case statement.

Comment: but you can't create a non-empty constructor of fragment class

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood the concept of `class` versus `object of class`. Your `MyFragment.java` source code defines `class` which you turn into "living thing" each time you **instantiate** it with `new` operator (`new MyFragment();`) - this creates `object` which is an `instance` of your `class`. Unless you intentionally prevent this (by i.e. using Singleton pattern) your can make as many `instances` of the `class` as you like, same way you are allowed to make as many i.e. cakes using single recipe. And this applies to fragments as well.

So as long as you create **separate** `object` (aka said `instance`) of your `class` for each page, you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: can you provide some sample for the above explanation..?