# How to reuse layouts/fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Hi there I am wondering what is the correct way if I would like to add different instance of a `Fragment` which uses the same `Layout` with different *content* in a `ViewPager`.

So for a better understanding I create my `Fragments` with an `createInstance()` method and pass an **id** with which it gets content *for a list from a database*. I add them to my `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

So what I get is the first `Fragment` added multiple times without getting its content for the actual **id**.

How could I force the `ViewPager` to treat the `Fragments` individually ?

***Edit:**

Okay I totally failed within my `createInstance()` method which was more a `getInstance()` method and returned the same instance every time...

Comment: Ideally, this issue will not occur. Can you post the code? for PagerAdapter and Fragment.

Comment: You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431907/use-one-fragment-in-a-viewpager-multiple-times or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263672/android-viewpager-using-a-single-fragment-on-multiple-pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Refer below

```
class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

       public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
           super(fm);
       }

       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return new PagerFragment(arrayListUri.get(position),position);
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return 0;
       }
}
```